# same code for different type database

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework

I am going to start an application in Asp.Net. In this app the database can be different but I want to use same C# code. That means for right now the database is SQL Server and its connection string will be defined in Web.Config file. But in later database may be MySQL or NETEZZA(IBM). But I want that only changing connection string but my C# logic should be same. How would I do it? Please suggest me. So For now I can not use any object of sql like SQLConnection or SQLCommand. I want to make it like generic.

Comment: the answer, at last partial, is in the tags you used.

Answer (score 0):

The partial answer is to use an ORM (EF, NHibernate). It won't be as simple as changing a single line to switch between them, but you won't need to rewrite your code. Adjusting a few config lines on the ORM should do the trick.